# Avoid duplicate document entry in mongodb spring boot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I hava collection Cars in mongodb.Each documents has fields like brand,model,color,horsepower,torque etc.I want each document to be unique and if entered again it shouldn't get added to collection.

If two fields are unique we can use function like this

```
 public interface CarRepo extends MongoRepository<Car,Long> {

    Optional<Car> findByBrandAndModel(String brand,String model);
}
```

Any suggestions if all the fields in document are unique ? I want to check before inserting document into collection.

Comment: Add to your `Car`'s field `@Indexed(unique=true)`

Comment: @valijon unique in the sense as a whole document,brand might repeat but not pair of brand and color.. I'm looking that way.If we use unique=true for every filed we can't repeat brand name Or any other field